# Background colour on click - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently when I click a link it sets the background colour to red. And keeps it red. How do I only set it to red for an `active` link? So I don't have multiple red background links.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/4dm318nn/16/

```js
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.inline').find('.navtoggle').click(function(){
        
      //Expand or collapse this panel
        $(this).css('background-color','red').next().slideToggle('fast');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".sub-menu").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    });
  });
```

```css
  .accordion-toggle {cursor: pointer;}
  .sub-menu {display: none;}
  .sub-menu .sub-menu {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="medium-8 columns primary menu">
 <ul class="inline naked">
        <li class="primary-item"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress">Home</a></li>      
  <li id="menu-item-74" class="primary-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-74"><a href="#" class="navtoggle">Dropdown 1</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-76"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=45">Dropdown 2</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-77" class="sub-sub-menu menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-77"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=47">Test 1</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-78"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=49">Test 2</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
        
              
  <li id="menu-item-89" class="primary-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-74"><a href="#" class="navtoggle">Dropdown 2</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-90" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-76"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=45">Dropdown 2</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-77" class="sub-sub-menu menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-77"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=47">Test 1</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-78"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=49">Test 2</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
        
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: WOW, huge ninjas from the guys below, but yeah it's just an extra line to add to jQuery :) https://jsfiddle.net/4dm318nn/19/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add one line before:

```
$('.navtoggle').css('background','none'); // make none before adding bgcolor
$(this).css('background-color','red').next().slideToggle('fast');
```

### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dm318nn/20/)

Answer (score 0):

Give all your link elements a common class, then set the background color of all elements within that class **before** setting the clicked link to red.

```
$('.commonClass').css('background-color', 'none');
$(this).css('background-color', 'red').next().slideToggle('fast');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.inline').find('.navtoggle').click(function(){
    $(".navtoggle").each(function () {
        $(this).css('background-color','')
    });
  //Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).css('background-color','red').next().slideToggle('fast');

  //Hide the other panels
  $(".sub-menu").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a class on the active element.

```
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.inline').find('.navtoggle').click(function(){
        $('.navtoggle').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      //Expand or collapse this panel
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".sub-menu").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    });
  });
```

**Example:**
https://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/4dm318nn/18/